# Session time calculation in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an events table in mysql with two columns: UserId,EventTime(datetime).
I need to calculate for each UserId two things:

1. Number of sessions
2. Sum of sessions lengths

A session end is defined by 2 minutes that there were no events for that user.

How can i write such a query?

So for example, for this user in the attached image, the number of sessions would be 2, the sum of session lengths would be 2 minutes and 34 seconds

[image]

Comment: I would go for a function, since you need something like a cursor

Comment: You can't do any of it?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu 5.6.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL.  One method uses a correlated subquery to identify the starts and then variables to assign a number to a session:

```
select e.*,
       (@s := if(@u <> userid or eventtime > prev_et + interval 2 minute, @s + 1
                 if(@u := userid, @s, @s)
                )
       ) as session_id
from (select e.*,
             (select max(e2.eventtime) from events e2 where e2.userid = e.userid and e2.eventtime < e.eventtime
             ) as prev_et
      from events e
      order by userid, eventtime
     ) e cross join
     (select @u := 1, @s := 0) params;
```